# Typescript multiple type mapping

Tags: typescript, types, mapping

I want to do some type mapping like this:

There are some modules with `id` and `actions`, I want to combine all actions method and remap its method name adding `${id}/` prefix, sample code is here:

```js
const m1 = {
  id: 'm1',
  actions: {
    down(id: string) {
      return true;
    },

    up(n: number) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

const m2 = {    
  id: 'm2',
  actions: {
    play(id: string) {
      return true;
    },

    go(n: number) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

type MyModule = ??

// should return :
// MyModule = {
//   'm1/down': (id: string) => boolean,
//   'm1/up': (n: number) => number;
//   'm2/play': (id: string) => boolean;
//   'm2/go': (n: number) => number;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgRhgXhgbwLACgYwJYAmAXDAOSKkA02uAhsFHuBCZjrjASAO5gAUhEtABOeMAHMAlOhodcwgKZQArsLAwow5QoDcs3AF9qWfTGUAHPmBJhlcAEYLh0tnPlLV6gAx72h2QbYgSZYoJCwcABMKOhysoJkUVSy9IzMrKbmADa0AJ4CxDAiYlIyfhyKKmoaWrqmRtim4iBWNnaOzmVuMJWeMD71AUGNWFC55gowALK5UyAEylmTqAD8KyMA9BtFABYgiwQ9HtVE2FvTs-OLy2XnuOQIG1y8pCQFQpol0sgAfDD2IBAS1oYGMd0SjwsrxgrRgtgcTm+f3hHV84PIkQ22Ty0PeRU+EiR-0BwLAaO29yiG2auOscPaiJQyIZwnJMGCIyAA)

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using mapped types and template literal types in newer versions of Typescript:

```
type ModuleDefnition = {
  id: string,
  actions: Record<string, (...a: any[]) => any>
}
type Module<T extends ModuleDefnition> = {} & {
  [P in keyof T['actions'] & string as `${T['id']}/${P}`]: T['actions'][P]
}

type MyModule = Module<typeof m1> & Module<typeof m2>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#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-jaRGw-stdqSvBjuHICDVghEpBI1Ukkvk0LhbhAIG2IKsifSKfsGd+ThgLncnjztaGnhCZfI8TVZUqVazEpkuZQ+cLxbArYDSYyar6PZrdeGjbnLejAai8yAA)

The only change to the module definitions is that for `id` you need to make sure you have a string literal type

You can also use `UnionToIntersection` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)) if you have an unknown number of modules or you want to create the modules using a function.

```
type DistributeModule<T extends ModuleDefnition> = T extends T ? Module<T> : never;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

function merge<T extends ModuleDefnition[]>(...a: T):UnionToIntersection<DistributeModule<T[number]>> {
  return null!;
}

let myModule = merge(m1, m2)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#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-GE4l+gD8a3djrhznUADdPCEzSiYABVI7gTEgACSYAJUggLxO7yTvpUoiT-pdQZBFRgodE7JISYUsOjIEIMCjsZGzsDtFEdZIsn2nhgGabMJbhCUoYz7ZgYBjnnm+y0YDu4Hgnjk6ix5Z7YfR5K9J0hMP+gL1CiIKfu6azObza7A7ytNrt6gd2-5LncnghMLh5wTG0LilKUACEIRRNg2ywHAFQfkkcCbuooiID8GQKPM2BAA)

Comment: Awesome answer!
I tried `[P in \`${T['id']}/keyof T['actions']\`]: T['actions'][P]` and stucked here, never thought can use `as` here.
And for the `const` id, `UnionToIntersection`, really resolved my problem, learned a lot from your answer, really thx :)